# copy files by length of filename on linux shell

Tags: linux, file, shell

How to copy files by length of filename on linux shell?
I have to copy all files with filename length 14 plus extension from a very large sized directory into another.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include directories, you could do it like this:

```
for file in *; do
    name="${file%.*}"
    [ ${#name} -eq 14 ] && cp -r "$file" /to/location
done
```

For only files:

```
for file in *; do
    name="${file%.*}"
    [ -f "$file" ] && [ ${#name} -eq 14 ] && cp "$file" /to/location
done
```

Comment: `ge` is probably a little too general, as it will match filenames that are longer than what the OP requested. Try `[ "${file%.*}" -eq 14 ]`, which test the length of the filename excluding the final `.` and everything that follows it.

Comment: @chepner Somehow, in haste, I miscomprehended the "length 14 plus extension part".  Thanks for pointing it out.  I used your suggestion to fix the post.

Comment: I edited your answer to avoid the use of the `-a` operator, which even the POSIX standard recommends against.

Comment: For 'only files' you actually don't need to test if it's a file or a directory. cp will only copy files and ommit any subdirectories.

That's why the -r is required to copy subdirs.

Comment: @mxlian Right, but the point is to see if it's a file first to avoid unnecessary processing of the next test and `cp` (returning an error).

Answer (score 3):

You can use globbing (filename expansion):

- A ? matches any single character.
- A * matches any string

You can use 14 ? and a * for the extension:

```
cp ??????????????.* /you/destination/dir
```

Comment: Note that usage of consecutive `?`s can be clunky if used in a script where the desired length might change frequently.  You'd either have to change it by hand every time or initiate an empty string variable and append a set number of `?`s to the variable in a loop.

Comment: You're right, point granted. 14 ? is already hard enough to count and you can not easily tell be looking at the code. However using it in a script is a different case of use, not described in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Using this `find` with `-regex`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./.{14}\..*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I % cp % /dest/
```

1. On OSX use `find -E` instead.
2. Use `-maxdepth 1` if you don't want `find` to be recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
 case $filename in
   ??????????????.*) 
   # do something with $filename when it has 14 characters and some extension
   ;;
   *)
   # otherwise
   ;;
 esac
```

you could put the above inside some adequate `for filename in *` loop.

Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
cp ??????????????.* /to/somewhere
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 14x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
cp ??????????????.* /destination/directory/path
```

No. of "?" should be equal to the file-name length you desire.
"*" to include all the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_dir=/09ccd9c864194bb2990088348369f291
cd ${data_dir}
for f in *
do
    len=${#f}
    if [ ${len} -le 80 ]  # if the file name is less than 80
        then
        echo ${f}
        # cp your files to some where
    fi
done
```

Comment: When adding an answer to a five year old question with six other answers it is useful to point out what new aspect of the question you are addressing. It is also useful to add explanation so your answer isn't a code only answer. In this particular case the question was asking for a file length of 14 plus extension, but your answer is using "less than 80".